# copy from one database to another using oracle sql developer - connection failed

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to copy a table from one database to another using oracle sql developer. I have the username, password and SIDs.

```
copy from uname1/password1@SID1 to uname2/pwd2@SID2 insert table1 (*) using (select * from message_table);
```

However I am getting the `connection failed` error.

The two databases are present in different host hosts (the hostname is different in connection properties).

The table has 5 million records and is too cumbersome to export/import

Comment: Has the dbLink been set up?  Will "select * from table@SID2" yield results?

Comment: `connection description for remote database not found`  This is what I am getting when I tried sid2 from sid1 worksheet

Comment: Insufficient privileges to create a database link

Comment: Sounds like you need to have your DBA set up a dbLink.  What makes it too cumbersome to export / import?  Just the size?

Comment: yes, and the columns. There are around 100 columns.

Comment: I have issues getting dbLinks set up as well, probably because I'm not in IT.  If you hit a brick wall and need a C# solution that will transfer a table, let me know.  It uses OCI (through ODP.net) and is very fast.

Comment: `copy` is a SQL*Plus command.  Last I looked, it had not been implemented in SQL Developer.  Can you use SQL*Plus instead?

Comment: if some errors occurs in executing any copy or create table query the sqldeveloper show connection failed error. Checking log and figuring out the error in query may help.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The `copy` command is a SQL*Plus command (not a SQL Developer command).  If you have your tnsname entries setup for SID1 and SID2 (e.g. try a tnsping), you should be able to execute your command.

Another assumption is that table1 has the same columns as the message_table (and the columns have only the following data types: CHAR, DATE, LONG, NUMBER or VARCHAR2).  Also, with an insert command, you would need to be concerned about primary keys (e.g. that you are not inserting duplicate records).

I tried a variation of your command as follows in SQL*Plus (with no errors):

```
copy from scott/tiger@db1 to scott/tiger@db2 create new_emp using select * from emp;
```

After I executed the above statement, I also truncate the new_emp table and executed this command:

```
copy from scott/tiger@db1 to scott/tiger@db2 insert new_emp using select * from emp;
```

With SQL Developer, you could do the following to perform a similar approach to copying objects:

1. On the tool bar, select Tools>Database copy.
2. Identify source and destination connections with the copy options you would like.
   [image]
3. For object type, select table(s).
   [image]
4. Specify the specific table(s) (e.g. table1).
   [image]

The copy command approach is old and its features are not being updated with the release of new data types.  There are a number of more current approaches to this like Oracle's data pump (even for tables).

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I am unable to find the object type under source and destination connections. I just have create object, Truncate object and drop object options.

Comment: I think I am using an older version. I will try this out and notify you

Comment: I know this feature is on SQL Developer 4.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the screenshots. So if I want to copy the data to a different table (say source table name is emp, but dest table name is emp1) is it possible I couldn't find this option anywhere

Comment: I agree that there is nothing to indicate one can copy and provide a different name to an object.  This option does not appear to exists. SQL*Plus will let you do this though.

Comment: I am trying to copy only one table but still it checks for all the tables which delays copying of data. As in following snapshot, There are too many sql statements checking for all objects before the final "select * from source" statement.

Any clue what is happening here?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/E583e.png