# Using HashMap dynamically for parameter mapping in mybatis

Tags: java, hashmap, mybatis

Okay so this is kinda re-posting of this question [Inserting HashMap Values to a table using ibatis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847761/inserting-hashmap-values-to-a-table-using-ibatis) (but I am looking for a different way - the answer wont work for me)..

**DB1GetStudentDataMapper.xml** (this queries to one database)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="com.testing.db1.DB1GetStudentDataMapper">

<select id="selectAllStudents" resultType="java.util.Map">
        SELECT STUDENT_CD, STUDENT_NM, PARENT_CD, CREATED_DATE
        FROM STUDENT
        WHERE STD_STATUS='ACT'
</select>

</mapper>
```

**DB2InsertStudentMapper.xml** (this queries to different database)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.testing.db2.DB2InsertStudentMapper">
                
<insert id="insertStudent" parameterType="java.util.HashMap">
  INSERT INTO STUDENT
  <!-- dynamically select column names from hashmap -->
  (#{stdMap.keySet}) // this is not working - its coming as null
   <!-- dynamically select values for the above columns from hashmap -->
   VALUES (#{stdMap.values}) // this is not working - its coming as null
</insert>
           
</mapper>
```

**DB2InsertStudentMapper.java**

```
public interface TMODSBDataRefreshMapper {
    
    void insertStudent(@Param("stdMap") HashMap stdMap);
}
```

**StudentDataProcess.java**

```
public class Student {
    
    // I have defaultExecutorType as BATCH in my mapper config file
    
        private DB1GetStudentDataMapper db1Mapper; // Interface Mapper for first data source
        private DB2InsertStudentMapper db2Mapper; // Interface Mapper for second data source
        
        public processStudent() throws Exception {
            
            List<HashMap> rs = db1Mapper.selectAllStudents(); // Gets some 15k+ records
            for(int i =0; i < rs.size(); i++) { // so this will loop through 15k+ records
                HashMap result = rs.get(i);
                System.out.println(result.keySet()); // prints column names from select query [STUDENT_CD, STUDENT_NM, PARENT_CD, CREATED_DATE]
                System.out.println(result.values()); // prints above column values of first data set [1001, Mike, 5001, 2021-07-01]
                
                // All I am trying is to insert above 15k records into different database dynamically rather than creating POJO
                db2Mapper.insertStudent(result);
            }
            
        }
            
}
```

> **Note**: Just for example I used 4 columns - I have some 150+ columns to work with..

PS: Please remember that this solution works better when you work with fewer columns - but doesn't work well if you have bulk insert - it effects performance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to show what you are trying to do.

Comment: Okay modifying my question again.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When iterating a map using `<foreach />`, the key and the value are assigned to the variables specified in `index` and `item` respectively.
So, your insert statement should look something like this.

```xml
<insert id="insertStudent">
  INSERT INTO STUDENT (
    <foreach collection="stdMap" index="col" separator=",">
      ${col}
    </foreach>
  ) VALUES (
    <foreach collection="stdMap" item="val" separator=",">
      #{val}
    </foreach>
  )
</insert>
```

- You must use `${}` for column names and `#{}` for values. See the [FAQ](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-difference-between--and-) for the details.
- To iterates the map in the same order, you should use `java.util.LinkedHashMap` as the result type of `<select />`.

Comment: great - this worked as expected.. thank you so much! but will it be any problem if we use foreach interms of performance or so when I have some 150+ columns to be inserted?

Comment:  There may be some difference for sure, but I wouldn't worry too much if you insert just one row at a time. If, on the other hand, you plan to insert a lot of rows using this statement and the performance matters, this may not be the best approach.

Comment: yes we are actually doing a BATCH insert.. it is taking much longer time with this statement.. any better alternate for inserting records faster through mybatis??

Comment: For such task (i.e. migrating data from one DB to another), there is little to no advantage in using MyBatis (or any persistence tool). A native command like [COPY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24459991/1261766) may be the fastest option. If it has to be done via JDBC, I would use JDBC directly with its batch processing API (i.e. `addBatch()` `executeBatch()`).  You might be able to make it somewhat dynamic by utilizing `ResultSetMetaData`.

Comment: Yeah makes sense.. ya both database have different tables or model.. so COPY command might not be an option for us..