# Mybatis - BatchInsert - Dynamic SQL

Tags: mybatis, batch-insert

Anyone used this following BatchInsert with mybatis: (the documentation is bit not clear for me interms of implementation)

https://mybatis.org/mybatis-dynamic-sql/docs/insert.html

Don't know where that insert() method is coming from (I dont think it is within mapper)

[image]

My requirememt is in here [Using HashMap dynamically for parameter mapping in mybatis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68213950/using-hashmap-dynamically-for-parameter-mapping-in-mybatis/68216214#68216214)

Due to performance issues I am not able to use the solution mentioned there. So just checking this mybatis dynamic sql..

Comment: There is a complete example here: https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-dynamic-sql/blob/ee63aa03170589bfcebd43a635571d5ba6abd112/src/test/java/examples/generated/always/mybatis/GeneratedAlwaysMapperTest.java#L109-L134

Comment: You can use MyBatis Generator to create some of the support classes for your table.