# Why does the mybatis map type not cause key-value pair confusion in the foreach loop

Tags: java, mybatis

The map type is unordered, but I tested hundreds of data without any confusion

xml like this:

```
        insert into AA
        <foreach collection="map.keySet()" item="key" separator="," open="(" close=")">
            ${key}
        </foreach>
        values
        <foreach collection="map.values()" item="val" separator="," open="(" close=")">
            #{val}
        </foreach>
```

interface code like this:

```
       int insertHT(@Param("map") Map<String, Object> map);
```

map is {"aa":"11","bb":"22"}

insertHT,I have performed this 100 times

I don't know whether this is correct or whether the data will always be inserted correctly

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1882804/1261766). If the order matters, you must use `LinkedHashMap` or `TreeMap` depending on your requirement (or some 3rd party implementation). I mentioned it in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68216214/1261766).

Comment: That's great I'll do it